# Integral of Logarithm with complex terms

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, complex-integration

Is there any way to evaluate this integral?
$$
\int_0^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{2\pi} \log(z-r e^{i\theta}) \; d\theta\right)r \; dr
$$
with $z\in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: Do you mean $\left(\log(z-re^{i\theta})\right)r$ or $\log\left((z-re^{i\theta})r\right)$?

Comment: Which branch of the logarithm do you want to use?

Comment: I consider $\{z:-\pi\lt \arg (z)\le\pi\}$

Comment: If $\ln$ is the principal branch and $|z| \geq 1$, the integrand is a harmonic function on the unit disk plus a constant function on a circular segment. We obtain
$$\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^1 r \ln(z - r e^{i t}) \, dr dt =
\pi \ln z - 2 \pi i S \, [x < 0] \big( [0 \leq y < 1] - [-1 < y < 0] \big), \\
S = \arccos |y| - |y| \sqrt {\smash [b] {1 - y^2}},
\quad z = x + i y,
\quad |z| \geq 1$$
(as expected, this is a continuous function of $z$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea if $|z|$ is large enough is that $\ln(z-re^{i\theta})$ is a power series in $e^{i\theta}$, but only the constant term doesn't vanish under $\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta$, and for that term it's as if $e^{i\theta}=0$, so $\int_0^{2\pi}\ln(z-re^{i\theta})d\theta=2\pi\ln z$ if $|z|>r$, making the integral $2\pi\ln z\cdot\int_0^1rdr=\pi\ln z$ if $|z|>1$. But if $|z|<1$, we need greater care. Use$$\ln(z-re^{i\theta})=i(\theta+(2n+1)\pi)+\ln r+\ln(1-\tfrac{z}{r}e^{-i\theta}),$$where the choice of $n\in\Bbb Z$ is a matter of the logarithm's branch. Again, the $\theta$-dependent logarithm admits a trivial behaviour under integration, and if we take $n=-1$ (as per @TomP's comment) the term $i(\theta+(2n+1)\pi)$ also integrates to $0$. If $|z|<1$,$$\int_0^{|z|}2\pi r\ln zdr+\int_{|z|}^12\pi r\ln rdr=\pi|z|^2\ln\frac{z}{|z|}-\tfrac12\pi+\tfrac12\pi|z|^2.$$This reduces to $\pi\ln z$ if $|z|=1$.

Comment: Very helpful, many thanks @J.G.

Comment: If you always choose the same branch of the logarithm, the integral is a continuous function of $z$ at all $z \in \mathbb C$, your result isn't. Otherwise you have to specify how you're choosing the branch for different $z$.