# Contour integral $\oint \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{2 \pi i z} \log(w+z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $\log:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R} \times i (-\pi,\pi]$ denote the principal branch of the complex logarithm. For $\omega \in \mathbb{C}$, I would like to calculate the contour integral
\begin{equation}
\oint_{\lvert z\rvert = 1} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{2 \pi i z} \log(w+z),
\end{equation}
I have been able to do this for all $\omega$ in $\mathbb{C}$ with $|\omega|>1$. Indeed, for such $\omega$ the function $\log(w+z)$ is holomorphic for $z \in \mathbb{D}$, and hence the Cauchy integral formula tells us that
\begin{equation}
\oint_{S^1} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{2 \pi i z} \log(w+z) = \log(w) \qquad \text{for $|\omega| > 1$}.
\end{equation}
What about when $|\omega| \leq 1$?

Comment: What is your $S_1$?

Comment: Thanks for point this out, S_1 is the unit circle. Added this to the question.

Comment: $z \mapsto \ln(z + w)$ with a fixed branch of $\ln$ cannot be analytic on the unit disk for all $w: |w| > 1$. For $|w| \geq 1$, the integral is
$$\ln w - i (\pi - 2 \arcsin |y|)
 [x < 0] \big( [0 \leq y < 1] - [-1 < y < 0] \big),$$
where $w = x + i y$ (compare with the comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3625145)).